# PagerSlidingTabStripをFragmentにしたい。

Tags: android

以下のコードはextends ActionBarActivityになっておりますが、これをextends FragmentやActivityにする事は可能でしょうか？一番行いたいのはFragmentに書き換える事ですが、もしも不可能であればActivityであればどのように行えばよいか伺いたいです。

可能であればどのように行えばよいかご教示頂けますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
public class PagerSlidingTabStrip extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));


        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_home:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private class TestAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"A", "B","C"};

        public TestAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new AFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new BFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }
    }
}
```

追記
通常Fragmnetで作った画面は特別な処理をしなくても、下記のような画像になります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、たとえば上記したようなコードをそのまま遷移させますと表示はされますが、
当然ActionbarActivityになってしまい、上記のような画像のActionbar??NavigationDrawerを開くものは表示されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

先ほど、ご教示いただいたDrawerの処理の部分の事だとは思うのですが、他のFragmentですと、特に処理を加えておりませんでしたので、どのような処理を加えればよいのかいまいち分かっておりません。。。
よろしければご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment`にも`Activity`にも出来ます。
`ActionBar`を使う場合、`ActionBarActivity`のままにして、`PagerSlidingTabStrip`の部分を`Fragment`にすればいいと思います。
`ActionBar`も含めて`Fragment`にしたい場合、`ActionBar`は`Fragment`には置けないため、`ToolBar`を利用すればいいと思います。
ただ、`ToolBar`を利用する場合、`Activity`に`ToolBar`を配置し、その下に`Fragment`などを配置するのが一般的だと思います。
なぜ`Fragment`にしたいかなどを教えてもらえれば、もうすこし具体的な回答が来ると思います。

追記
コメントに対する回答です。

それであれば、`ActionBarActivity`のままでいいと思います（クラス名は変えたほうがいいと思いますが）。

こんな構成ではどうでしょう？
* MainActivity
`ActionBarActivity`を継承。`ActionBar`および`Drawer`の処理を行う。
`Drawer`のメニュー選択により`Fragment`を切り替えする。
* TabFragment
`Fragment`を継承。`PagerSlidingTabStrip`を配置。

「FragmentでPagerSlidingTabStripの例」の件は特に`Fragment`だから特殊なことは必要なく、`Activity`で使っていた方法がそのまま使えると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
初心者なので、言葉足らずかとは思いますが、お伝えさせて頂きますと
NavigationDrawerを使っておりまして、
onItemClickNavigationの画面遷移先をFragmentで全ておいております。ActionBarで置き換えてしまうと、NavigationDrawerのhomeボタン（メニューを開くボタン）も置き換えられてしまうため、Fragmentでやった方がよいのかと思っておりました。しかし、FragmentでPagerSlidingTabStripの例が発見できず、質問させて頂いたという経緯になります。

Comment: 特に今まで、DrawerLayoutの遷移先のFragmenrtではtoolbar等の指定もしておりませんでした。なので、初心者的憶測では、toolbarも要らないのかなと思います。

Comment: 先ほど、質問に追記させていただきました。
今までFragmentですと、特に処理を加えておりませんでしたので、どのような処理を加えるべきか、イマイチピントきておりません。
もしよろしければ、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: すみません。追記されたものが理解出来ませんでした。もう少し詳しく教えていただけますか？

Answer (score 1):

**追記ですが長いので新たに回答を作成します**

作成したい構成はこんな感じでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記画像のような構成でしたら、下記のようなコードになりますが、どのへんが分からない（それともこのような構成でなない？）のでしょうか？

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private ListView mMenuListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // DrawerToggleの設定
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        mToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        // DrawerのListViewに表示するメニュー
        String[] items = {"メニュー1", "メニュー2", "メニュー3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        // DrawerのListViewの設定
        mMenuListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_menu_listview);
        mMenuListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mMenuListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            // DrawerのListViewの選択イベント
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        // 一番目の項目が選択された場合はFragmentAを表示
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FragmentA.newInstance()).commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // 二番目の項目が選択された場合はFragmentBを表示
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FragmentB.newInstance()).commit();
                        break;
                }
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mMenuListView);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#eeddee"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public static FragmentA newInstance() {
        return new FragmentA();
    }

    public FragmentA() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        // ViewPagerにMyPagerAdapterを設定
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity()));

        // PagerSlidingTabStripにViewPagerを設定
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        return view;
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        // ページ内容データ
        private String[] mContents = {"ページ1", "ページ2", "ページ3", "ページ4", "ページ5"};
        private Context mContext;

        public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mContents.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // とりあえず「タイトルn」を表示
            return "タイトル" + (position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // とりあえずTextViewを表示
            TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setText(mContents[position]);
            container.addView(textView);
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }
    }
}
```

### fragment_a.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### FragmentB.java

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    public static FragmentB newInstance() {
        return new FragmentB();
    }

    public FragmentB() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }
}
```

### fragment_b.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="フラグメント2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 拙い説明を汲み取って頂きましてありがとうございます。
私が行いたかったのは、yuki様に教えて頂いたものそのままになります。
教えて頂いた方法でFragmentA.javaを書き換えた所、しっかりと作動しました・
とても、御丁寧に教えて頂きましてありがとうございます。
まだまだ初心者ですが、今後しっかり勉強していき、私もyuki様のように
丁寧に教える事のできるプログラマ目指して頑張ります。
本当にありがとうございました。